# yeoman gruntコマンドの最中に停止する

Tags: gruntjs

**yeoman**を使用していまして
**gruntコマンド**を実行すると

```
Running "sass:server" (sass) task
Done, without errors.
```

上記のメッセージを出力して停止しています。
原因をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご回答お願いいたします。

Comment: とりあえず二行目は「エラーなく完了した」というメッセージなのですが、これ以外に何か期待と違う挙動でもしているのでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist コメントありがとうございます。エラーメッセージ等出力されないので挙動が間違っているのか確認出来ていません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grunt serve` であればサーバーが起動し（＝ `grunt` が終了しない）ブラウザが開くはずですが、 `grunt` だけであれば特に問題ない動作結果に見えます。

「ページが正しく表示されない」等の問題が起きてから、改めて考えればいいのではないでしょうか。

なお、 `grunt` を実行したときに何が行われるかは generator によって異なります。その generator が何を行うものなのかは、 generator の README や、実際に展開された `Gruntfile.js` を読んでみるのが確実かと思います。